# Проблема MemoryError в Python 3 при распозновании json

Tags: json, python-3.x, requests

Столкнулся с проблемой в Python.
Стоит задача - спарсить JSON с сервера. Объект размером 4-10ГБ. Я не знаю зачем это сделали люди, я не одобряю такой подход. :) Запросить часть JSON нельзя, только целиком.
Я пользуюсь requests и отправляю POST-запрос на получение JSON. Он загружается в течение некоторого времени. При попытке его последующего разбора с помощью метода json() или даже text я получаю MemoryError, т.к. память резко скачет вверх ровно настолько же, сколько весит JSON(учитывая, что переменная самого запроса также занимает в памяти объем, равный размеру JSON).
Таким образом, спарсить не получается.

Answer (score 2):

Можно для этих целей использовать модуль [`ijson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/). Он обрабатывает json потоком, а не блоком, поэтому проблем с нехваткой памяти не должно возникнуть.

P.S. Можете попробовать [`json-streamer`](https://github.com/kashifrazzaqui/json-streamer). Судя по описанию, он позволяет обработать частичный json-файл, например, когда вы скачали лишь часть от целого файла, и его необходимо обработать.

Comment: Сомневаюсь что Питон объект, соответствующий 10GB json, будет меньше места занимать. Так что автору лучше на лету на события реагировать, не распознавая json целиком, чтобы взять только необходимую информацию—оба предложенных модуля вероятно это умеют (они используют одну и ту же библиотеку за кадром).